# Cloudflare return when attempting to send get request via python to official Etherscan api

Tags: python, api, captcha, cloudflare, etherscan

When attempting to gather data from the Etherscan API with a Valid API key via a python (requests module) get request. Instead of receiving the expected data, I am met with the html src code for a CloudFlare CAPTCHA page. (I wouldn't expect this to happen with an official API).

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xbd90cA199FB00579d87d0536b8389953dF035830&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=1000&sort=asc&apikey=MyApiKey"
    print(s.get(url).text)
```

The response head: (Visiting the API URL myself, I don't in counter this message which is obviously the point to protect against web crawling but CloudFlare shouldn't be triggered in this context):

```
<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>

<meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>
```

Comment: So what do you want us to do without any code or [mre] to look at?